# Jcarousel Images loads in list then conform to horizontal block

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I have a jcarousel of images on D7. On IE, the images will load in a list then once all the images are loaded. They conform to the horizontal scroll box. I've read on several articles about adding the `overflow:hidden` to the css and I have. It still appears to be loading in the list. How I can make the images not appear in a list prior to conforming to the horizontal box?

The site is www.jlucina.com and you can find the product scrolls on any of the product pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting `overflow:hidden` you also need to give the same element a static height, e.g.

```
#slideshow-wrapper{overflow:hidden;height:300px;}
```

Comment: I tried it with the height specified and it still does it. I'm using just the jcarousel implemented through views. I'm I missing something?

Comment: It's been such a long time since I used IE7 but I think there was a bug with overflow that meant you had to set `position:relative;` on the container element. Can you try that?

Comment: A quick search on SO seems to [confirm it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403011/ie6-ie7-css-problem-with-overflow-hidden-position-relative-combo)

Comment: My apologize, Its not just on I.E but I will try the position fix.